# wspace and hspace in subplots, width of axes - python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, subplot

**How to make wspace and hspace in subplots?** I have a code of type:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))

fig1=plt.subplot(231)
plt.plot(x, y)

fig2=plt.subplot(232)
plt.plot(x, y)

fig3=plt.subplot(233)
plt.plot(x, y)

fig4=plt.subplot(234)
plt.plot(x, y)

fig5=plt.subplot(235)
plt.plot(x, y)

fig6=plt.subplot(236)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

I tried to make bigger the wspace for individual figures:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))

fig1=plt.subplot(231)
fig1.subplots_adjust(wspace=2)
```

The error:

```
    fig1.subplots_adjust(wspace=2)
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'subplots_adjust'
```

**And how to change the width of all axes?**

I tried:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error because subplot returns an Axes object and subplots_adjust is a Figure method. If you want to have both Figure and Axes objects returned, you need to call subplots. Otherwise, you can simply call plt.subplots_adjust().

Comment: Thank you, do you mean this?
`plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=3)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=3)` Nothing has changed.

Comment: I mean, you can define your figure and axes this way. `fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3)` and then call subplots_adjust on the figure object. One call is enough, you can pass multiple arguments at once.

Comment: I tried it but the subplot have different size and the spaces didn't change. Is it possible to set it individual?

Comment: Wait... Is it the actual size of each subplot that you want to change? Because if yes, then subplots_adjust might not be what you are looking for. Do you want all axes to be the same size and pad the entire figure, or something else?

Comment: I want to make more space for labels. I added a figure to my question. I would like to continue in my structure of code, because there are another settings for individual subplots.

Comment: OK, so I would first call fig.tight_layout(). Then, if it is still not satisfactory, call subplots_adjust with both height and width arguments. It should work and give you more space for the labels.